# Get the value of a radio button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this portion of code:

```js
var checkout_options = $("#checkout").find("input[type='radio']");
    $('#button-account').on('click', function () {
            alert(checkout_options.value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkout">
    <p>Checkout Options:</p>
    <label for="register">
        <input type="radio" name="account" value="register" id="register" checked>
        <b>Register Account</b></label>
    <br>
    <label for="guest">
        <input type="radio" name="account" value="guest" id="guest">
        <b>Guest Checkout</b>
    </label>
  <input type="button" value="Continue" id="button-account">
</div>
```

What I want it is to get the value of the selected radio button but with my code I only get the first radio button value, the second radio does not work.
Kindly help me fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer the element inside the callback. So get value by using **[`this.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)** or **[`$(this).val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)** method. Although avoid [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo-class selector otherwise it only selects the first element.

```js
var selected = $("#checkout").find("input[type='radio']");
    selected.change(function(){
        alert(this.value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkout">
    <p>Checkout Options:</p>
    <label for="register">
        <input type="radio" name="account" value="register" id="register" checked>
        <b>Register Account</b></label>
    <br>
    <label for="guest">
        <input type="radio" name="account" value="guest" id="guest">
        <b>Guest Checkout</b>
    </label>
</div>
```

---

You can make it simpler using [`:radio`](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) pseudo-class selector

```js
$("#checkout :radio").change(function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkout">
  <p>Checkout Options:</p>
  <label for="register">
    <input type="radio" name="account" value="register" id="register" checked>
    <b>Register Account</b>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="guest">
    <input type="radio" name="account" value="guest" id="guest">
    <b>Guest Checkout</b>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your help but it does not work. Try your code

Answer (score 1):

Your handler is only being attached to the radio button that is checked, so no handler exists for the second radio button. Attach a handler to both radio buttons:

```
var $radioBtn = $( "#checkout" ).find( "input[type='radio']" );

$radioBtn.on( 'change', function() {
  if ( this.checked ) {
    alert( this.value );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work, because you register the event handler for the initially checked value only. This is how to make it dynamically reflect the value change:

```
var selected = $("#checkout").find("input[name='account']");
selected.change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This also makes sure that only the current radio button group is included, so you can have additional ones.

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sjmhdasw/

Answer (score 1):

Just use

`$("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
    console.log(this.id + " checked !");
});`

It binds an event listener on all the inputs of type radio !

No need to store the selectors inside a variable *(unless you're doing something with it, somewhere else in your code)*